# symfony entity catching up inversed Values in many to many

Tags: symfony, entity

I'm trying to setup a many to many between fos Userbundle and my own group bundle so that I can group users. this is working fine. I can set a new group and can add as many users to this group as I like to. But when I want to check if a user is in a group, I get a Index join Column error. I think I didn't understand the usage of manytomany the correct way so it would be nice if you can help me getting the point.

My entities look like:

User:

```
    class User extends BaseUser
{
  /**
* @ORM\Column(type="integer")
* @ORM\Id
* @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
*/
protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $usergroups;
//....//
```

And my Group Entity looks like:

```
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="PrUserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="id")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * @var user
     */

    private $user;
//....
    /**
     * Add user
     *
     * @param \PrUserBundle\Entity\User $user
     * @return Lieferanten
     */
    public function addUser(\PrUserBundle\Entity\User $user)
    {
        $this->user[] = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove user
     *
     * @param \PrUserBundle\Entity\User $user
     */
    public function removeUser(\PrUserBundle\Entity\User $user)
    {
        $this->user->removeElement($user);
    }

    /**
     * Get user
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }
```

When I try to catch all users in a group, I get an error:

```
$group=$em->getRepository('PrGroupBundle:Group')->findAll();
var_dump($lfr[0]->getUser()->getId());
```

I guess I missunderstood how to handle the bidirectional manytomany. Or can I use a manytoone also?

Comment: Could you post the error message?

Comment: The error message is: "Notice: Undefined index: joinColumns"

Comment: `inversed` should point to an other ManyToMany defined property. But I think you'll need a OneToMany Relation here, 'cause a user can't be multiple times in the same group, right?

Comment: Yes that is true indeed. Thank you for this point of view cause i am a bit confused for all the possibilities :):) I will check it out and get back to you with the solution on how i did it.